# Can I sell software license I bought?

Tags: contract-law, software

I bought this very expensive MapInfo license (>1500$), now I'm not using this software very much and want to sell my license online.
Can I just sell it or do I need their consent?
Also, if it's still in maintenance, would the buyer enjoy the maintenance like warranty on a car?

The T&C they have say nothing about this subject. I live in the UK.

Comment: Do the T & C state if this is "transferable" ?

Comment: no, it's not mentioned at all whether it is transferable or not. It says 'perpetual' though, it's a perpetual license